# How to move X and Y line's points to different array Kineticjs

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs

I have create Line

```
var line1=new Kinetic.Line({

stroke:"blue",
strokeWidth:10,
points:[{"x":152,"y":176},{"x":152,"y":399},{"x":271,"y":399},{"x":271,"y":487},{"x":401,"y":487},{"x":401,"y":370},{"x":541,"y":370},{"x":541,"y":262},{"x":293,"y":262},{"x":293,"y":177}],

})
```

To save the points I do this,

```
var linearray=new Array
linearray=line.getPoints()
```

It works, now I want to save that points X and Y in different Array just like this,

```
var linex=new Array()
linex=line.getPoints().x

var liney=new Array()
linex=line.getPoints().y
```

It doesn't work, Any idea?

Update:
here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/skarat001/8kgKx/

Comment: Can you share the fiddle ?

Comment: in jsfiddle you have not write array even a single time. show your exact problem. where is theser lines ? var linearray=new Array
linearray=line.getPoints()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would propose this :

```
var linex=new Array();
var liney=new Array();

for (var i in line1.getPoints()) {
    linex.push(line1.getPoints()[i].x);
    liney.push(line1.getPoints()[i].y);
}
```